# export global variable defined in react styles js file

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have separated `styles.js` and `app.js` for a simple app. And I have image resources defined as global constant variables. (For logos and profiles) I tried to add these constant image resources in `styles.js` as well. But with my current method and syntax, I can't export these constant image resources from `styles.js` because they are no defined in styles variable wrapper.

**styles.js**:

```
 'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

/*
  const background_img= require("../../resource/mybackground.png");
  I tried to define the resource path here
*/

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   /*Styles Definition*/
});

export default styles
```

**app.js**:

```
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View, Image,
TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles.js';

/*const background= require("../../resource/mybackground.png");*/
// I want to move this part to styles.js


export class LoginScene extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image
         style={[styles.background, styles.container]}
         source={background} //I want to replace to styles.background_img
         resizeMode="cover"
      ></Image>
      /*Other view definitions*/
    );
  }
}

export default LoginScene
```

I've indicated where I want to make my change in the above code with comment. If I want to route the source file as what I did above, what should I change in `styles.js` so that I can export the constant global variables at the same time with styles variable wrapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can export styles as default, then you can also export another variable which can contain a value or an object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export const assets = {
  background: require("../../resource/mybackground.png"),
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   /*Styles Definition*/
});

export default styles;
```

then you can just import the default and the named exports when needed:

```
import styles, { assets } from './styles.js';
```

Comment: I see, this works. So it means we can only export json object from other `*.js` files?

Comment: Not exactly, you can export variables, constants, functions, classes, arrays, objects. Just remember that you can use only one `export default` per file. Check out this guide about es6 modules: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand the imporrt of a global variable.